# jQuery UI Autocomplete perform search on button click issues

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a working UI Auto complete with jQuery. I wanted to change the way it worked. Instead of a new browser tab opening with the user selects a value from the list I wanted the user to first pick a value then click a search button to trigger the event.

It works but if you perform a search and then a second search it will trigger the previous URL and new URL at the same time. Also if you perform a search then click the search button without typing anything into the search input it triggers the previous search. Weird right? I'll add my code but I think a codepen example will help clarify what I mean.

The other issue I was having is I am trying to set up a custom alert if the value typed is not in the array but I get the invalid error message no matter what I type. I added that as well in the code. It is one of the if statements.

JS

```
var mySource = [
   {
       value: "Google",
       url: "http://www.google.com"
   },
   {
       value: "Yahoo",
       url: "https://www.yahoo.com"
   },
   {
       value: "Hotmail",
       url: "https://hotmail.com"
   },
   {
       value: "Reddit",
       url: "https://www.reddit.com"
   }
];

//Logic for ui-autocomplete
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(req, resp) {
            var q = req.term;
            var myResponse = [];
            $.each(mySource, function(key, item) {
                if (item.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) === 0) {
                    myResponse.push(item);
                }
                if (item.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(q) === 0) {
                    myResponse.push(item);
                }
                //Add if statement here to determine if what the user inputs is in the 
                // array
                //and if not in the array give an error to #textAlert.
                //Example
                if (item.value.indexOf(q) != myResponse) {
                    $('#alertText').text("Invalid Search");
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            resp(myResponse);
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#appSearchBtn').one("click", function() {
                window.open(ui.item.url);
                $('#appsearch').val('');
               return false;
            });
        }
    });
});

//Input and ui text clears when clicked into
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = document.querySelector('#appsearch');
    var ui = document.querySelector(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible");
    input.onclick = function() {
        input.value = '';
        ui.textContent = '';
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<p id="alertText"></p>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="appsearch" class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Application Search" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary inputBtn" id="appSearchBtn" type="button">Search</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is a Code pen https://codepen.io/FrontN_Dev/pen/MEmMRz so you can see how it works. I also added how it should work and what the bugs are.

9/29/17 @0732
I resolved the issue with the event firing the same URL over and over but I still need help with the custom invalid search message that appears for every search even if the value is in the array.

Comment: It appears it was a lot simpler than I thought. I just needed to use .one("click", function..... instead of on("click".......
Well I hope this helps someone else out.